# Why sqlalchemy declarative base object has no attribute 'query'?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I created declarative table.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

I need to filter data. In the `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, I do

```py
name = 'foo'
User.query.filter_by(name=name).first()
```

But if I use `SQLAlchemy` without Flask, then I get the error:

> type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'

The only way that works for me is to filter the data through the `session`.

```py
engine = create_engine('DATABASE_URL')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

name = 'foo'
user = session.query(User).filter_by(name=name).first()

session.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Model.query...` idiom is not a default part of the SQLAlchemy ORM; it's a [customisation](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/9b1d48ff74b86925fcef092b458b1e29ffccd2a0/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L450) provided by [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery).  It is not available in base SQLAlchemy, and that is why you get the error message.

Comment: (Old) vanilla SQLA has an easy enough method for the same as well, if using `scoped_session`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property

Answer (score 2):

Why? ...because query object is not set on Base/model object automatically.

Solution is to add this line to your base:

```py
Base.query = SessionLocal.query_property()
```

(where `SessionLocal` is instance of `scoped_session`)

This will make query available on all of your models and should solve your issue.However, mypy and pylint will still be complaining about this (that's how I found this question).